# Copying from one field to another in the same content type drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type called "Publications" and in that content type I have two fields, "first author" and "authors". I already have created a lot of content with both fields and both of them have a lot of information in them.
What I need to do is copy or move everything from the field "first author" to the field "authors" Both fields are node references and I'm using Drupal 7.

Is this possible with a module or maybe from SQL. I don't know what to do, I've been trying to do this from weeks and I'm stuck :( please help!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a module to do this.

You will need a function that does something like this:

```
<?php 
$type = "publications"; 
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type)); 
foreach($nodes as $node){
    $node->field_authors[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = $node->field_first_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid']; 
    node_save($node);
}
?>
```

For a standalone script, you would need to add the following:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Then the above code.

You would therefore have a php called updateAuthors.php with the following contents:

```
<?php
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

    $type = "publications"; 
    $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type)); 
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        $node->field_authors[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = $node->field_first_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid']; 
        node_save($node);
    }
?>
```

To add the value in first_author as a new node_reference in field_authors, you need to do something like this:

```
<?php
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

    $type = "publications"; 
    $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type)); 
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        $firstAuthor = $node->field_first_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid']; 
        if ($firstAuthor === false){
            continue;
        }
        $numberOfValuesInFieldAuthors = count($node->field_authors[LANGUAGE_NONE]);
        $node->field_authors[LANGUAGE_NONE][$numberOfValuesInFieldAuthors]['nid'] = $firstAuthor
        node_save($node);
    }
?>
```

This will skip any nodes that don't have a first author set, and for nodes that do have one set, will add the value in field_first_author as a new node reference in the field_authors field

Comment: As an alternative to writing a module, you could simply place a php file in the drupal root directory, include the bootstrap include, then add the above code - you will then just need to navigate to the script in your browser. E.g. http://localhost/migrate-authors.php

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I'm a Drupal newbie and am lost with this. How would I write a module? is it difficult? and how would it work? the code only mentions the field_authors, how does it know to grab all field_first_author and copy them there?

Sorry for all the questions, I just really need the help! The other option was to place the php file in the drupal root directory, but what do you mean by include the "bootstrap include" what is that and how do I include that?

Thanks so much for your help, hopefully you can help me some more :)

Comment: I'd made a typo, the field name referenced on the right hand side of the assignment operator should have been the field_author. I've updated my answer above with info on including the drupal bootstrap code which loads all the drupal functions and modules

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm still not seeing how the fields in "field_first_author" are all copied into the field "field_authors". should I change the code so it says: "$node->field_authors[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = $node->field_first_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'];"?

And does it matter that there are already some data in the "field_first_author" field? and as well, does it matter that those two fields are reference nodes? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Or should it be the other way around maybe:

"$node-> field_first_author[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = $node-> field_authors[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'];"?

Comment: I've updated the field names above. I'm not sure if either of your node reference fields allows multiple values but the above code will take the first node ref in field_first_author and copy it to field_authors overwriting the first reference in that field with the value from field_first_author

Comment: Thanks PiX06! the only thing is that it would override the first value of the field field_authors, is there a way I can make it copy the field at the end of the field field_authors? I have it set to allow unlimited values. And the field field_authors in the content type already has several values, so I wanted to copy the  field_first_author to the end of the field field_authors. Is there a way to have it insert at the end as an additional value in the field field_authors instead of overriding a value that it's already there? Thanks so much!

Comment: I've updated my answer again to match your requirements

Comment: You're a genius PiX06!!!! worked like a charm, for some reason the require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
was not working but I changed it to
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
 require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
 drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
and that worked great! OMG, thank you soooo much!!!!